# @username editado em comentário não gerou notificação

Tags: bug, suporte, status-pronto, notificações

Na pergunta [Paginação por demanda com Angular ou JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16737/paginacao-por-demanda-angular-javascript), o autor deixou um comentário para mim sem `@`. Outro usuário aconselhou que ele usasse `@` para que eu fosse notificado. O autor então editou o comentário e incluiu a `@`, mas eu não recebi notificação alguma.

Isso contradiz os testes que alguns usuários relataram ter feito em *[Do users get notifications when @ was edited in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in)*.

Como isso funciona exatamente então? Editar uma referência a um usuário não gera mais notificação? Ou seria um bug isso não ter funcionado?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi nos testes dos comentários, ninguém conseguiu reproduzir o erro, certo?

Comment: O teste na resposta do Andorinha era outro... Pra mim isto ainda é um bug.

Comment: Eu tenho um palpite... Testei mas percebi que era besteira, já que o post é seu e você ia receber notificação de qualquer jeito

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que foi porque ele usou o **!** depois do seu nome e então o StackOverflow entendeu como se o **!** fizesse parte do seu nome e por isso como não existe um usuário que se chama **bfavaretto!** então ele não notificou ninguém. Mas se ele alterar de novo e fazer isso **bfavaretto !** aí pode ser que funcione.

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade, então acho que não é isso, vamos apagar os comentários que fizemos de testes e outras perguntas..

Answer (score 1):

O Jarrod consertou o problema e já está no ar. Não sei o que aconteceu e os testes são complicados de fazer.

Vou marcar como [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto) mas se alguém perceber que se repetiu, basta vir aqui avisar.